# 'B': "{:0<4.0f}" | How should I read this?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

While studying [Pandas Style](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html), I got to the following:

```
df.style.format("{:.2%}")
```

Which I understand means, turn every value to 2 decimal places and add a `%` in the end.

Just after that, there is:

```
df.style.format({'B': "{:0<4.0f}", 'D': '{:+.2f}'})
```

How should I read `'B': "{:0<4.0f}"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the "new" formatting string syntax, explained in https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language.

- The first `0` means pad with "0"
- The `<` means [align](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#grammar-token-align) to the left (so the number will be followed by a bunch of 0's, e.g. '4' will be formatted as "400000…")
- The `4` means the [minimum width](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#grammar-token-width) is 4 characters
- The `.0` means the [precision](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#grammar-token-precision) is 0, i.e. don't show any decimal parts.
- The `f` means the [type](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#grammar-token-type) is a fixed-point number.

Examples:

```
>>> '{:0<4.0f}'.format(1)
'1000'
>>> '{:0<4.0f}'.format(3.14)
'3000'
>>> '{:0<4.0f}'.format(26)
'2600'
>>> '{:0<4.0f}'.format(77777)
'77777'
>>> '{:0<4.0f}'.format(-3)
'-300'
```

Comment: Ok, I think I got it. But, also think, the table just below `df.style.format({'B': "{:0<4.0f}", 'D': '{:+.2f}'})` in the reference (in the question) is wrong. Because there `'{:0<4.0f}'.format(132.92)` evaluates to `1000 ` (in column B).

Comment: @KcFnMi: You're right, 132.92 will be formatted to `1330`. The output of this format (`0<`) is very confusing to human, I don't think there's any actual reason of using `0<` for numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The [Python documentation for format strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) explains what this means.

In the case of `0<4.0f`, it means:

```
0     0-filled
<     left-aligned
4.0   width.precision (4 digits wide, 0 after decimal point)
f     floating-point number
```

Answer (score 0):

As according to the [Pandas Style documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/style.html#Finer-Control:-Display-Values) you linked to, it's a python [format specification string](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language).

The specific options break down to:

- `0<` Forces the field to be left-aligned within the available space, and pads with zeros
- `4` Specifies the width of the field
- `.0` Specifies the precision of the number, i.e. how many decimal points should be displayed
- `f` Displays the number as a fixed-point number.